# WPF WrapPanel - all items should have the same width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, wrappanel

I have a ListBox whose ItemsPanel I have replaces with a WrapPanel.
The WrapPanel now hosts the databound ListboxItems. Each item has a variable sized text in it, giving each item a different width.
However, I want the width to be constant so that all items have the same width as the item with the longest text.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Place each item in a single-row, single-column (auto width) grid, and name the column. Set Grid.IsSharedSizeScope on the ListBox and all grids will have the same width.

Comment: +1. With this, I could take the final leap with changing my gui from a (horizontal) `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer`, with variable size items, into a `WrapPanel` with all items sharing the same size. Really great stuff.

Comment: The effect is marvelous...even if it feels like a bit of a hack, it beats making a new custom control for this crap...hehe

Comment: Here's a [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524453/wrappanel-trying-to-make-the-itemwidth-equal-to-the-max-width-of-any-one-elemen?noredirect=1&lq=1)