# Binding ObservableCollection to Grid Inside a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Right now I have a listbox inside which a scrollviewer and a stackpanel is placed with the data binding to the observablecollection of imagelist.

I am having a photolist class which holds the image and path of it and binding it to the listbox.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
          <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
          </ScrollViewer>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The above code works fine showing the listbox with a scroller and stackpanel hosting the multiple images.

Now I would like to modify the listbox to have scrollviewer and a grid instead of stackpanel, so that the images are positioned like the matrix form.

Please provide me a code snippet to bind the photolist to the grid(inside a scrollviewer which is inside a listbox).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a WrapPanel and if you require the cells to all be the same size use the answer from here: [WPF WrapPanel - all items should have the same width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817620/wpf-wrappanel-all-items-should-have-the-same-width)

Comment: Hi scroog, I did change the stackpanel to wrappanel, but If I have the scrollviewer the wrappanel works just like the stackpanel. If I remove the scrollviewer the images get populated in the grid fashion. How do I have both scrollviewer and wrappanel behaving like grid.

Comment: @Scrogg, After changing the visibility of the scrollviewer, things just works fine as expected. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You could try specifying the width of the WrapPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your style to use the WrapPanel:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="6">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="120" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"  />
</Style>
```