# How justify items in a wrap panel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, wrappanel

By using a wrap panel in WPF you can arrange items horizontaly.

Example here : [WPF Tutorial | Wrap Panel](http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html)

Now I want to space items equaly in order to fill the whole width. Like text justify, but items instead of words. How can I achieve this ?

Edit : I show you what I have actually :

[image]

I pick countries in the bottom list, and display selected countries in border within a  wrappanel.

I want to adjuste automatically space between borders to get Spain and Thailand justified to right like Singapour.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817620/wpf-wrappanel-all-items-should-have-the-same-width

Comment: use grid, specify the number of columns and share the width. see the below link

Comment: I want change space bewtween items, items could be of different widths

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I can think of that you can do that in WPF is for you to create a new custom `Panel` class. You could use this `Panel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` in a collection control like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourJustifyPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

You can find out to create a custom `Panel` from the following links:

[How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html)
[Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF)

It will be challenging, but it is possible. Unfortunately, there is no easy option for this requirement. Good luck.